# PHP Parsing Text and Description SimpleXML

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to parse the text and description field from the code provided:

```
<?
$news = simplexml_load_file('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=mandarin%20comics&format=xml&limit=1');

foreach($news->section->item as $item) {
    echo "<strong>" . $item->text . "</strong><br />";
    echo strip_tags($item->description) ."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

It's giving me this error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 4
```

How can I fix this?

Var_dump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (3) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "2.0" } ["Query"]=> string(15) "mandarin comics" ["Section"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["Item"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) { ["Text"]=> string(17) "Mandarin (comics)" ["Description"]=> string(109) "The Mandarin is a fictional character, a supervillain who appears in comic books published by Marvel Comics. " ["Url"]=> string(46) "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_(comics)" } } }
```

Here is a link to the xml page: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=mandarin%20comics&format=xml&limit=1

Comment: What's in `$news`? Is it formatted as you expected? Did your `xml_file_load` call work? Try using `var_dump($news)` to see what you're working with.

Comment: can you improve your question with a piece of xml?

Comment: I updated the post to show what var_dump reveals.

Comment: there may be more than one section in the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case sensitive, so:

```
foreach($news->Section->Item as $item) {
    echo "<strong>" . $item->Text . "</strong><br />";
    echo strip_tags($item->Description) ."<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want iterate the item of array `$news->section` (supposed that section is an array) you should correct the code so:

```
<?
$news = simplexml_load_file('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=mandarin%20comics&format=xml&limit=1');

foreach($news->Section as $section) {
    echo "<strong>" . $section->Item->Text . "</strong><br />";
    echo strip_tags($section->Item->Description) ."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```